# Parseval identity

Tags: fourier-analysis, parsevals-identity

I am reading [LECTURE NOTES 2 FOR 247A,TERENCE TAO](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/247a.1.06f/notes2.pdf). At the beginning of the paragraph the author defines the fourier trasform $\mathcal{F}f$ of a function $f$ and the hypothesis is that $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^{d})$. Then at pg. $19$ he says that for a function $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^{2d})$ one has $$\langle f, g \rangle =\langle \mathcal{F}f, \mathcal{F}g \rangle.$$

The author defines $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$  in [LECTURE NOTES 1 FOR 247A, TERENCE TAO](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/247a.1.06f/notes1.pdf) pg. $28$ formula $(20)$.

Is it right to interpret  $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle $ as the classical pairing between a space $X$ and its dual $X'$?

If yes, does this means that If I suppose additionally $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ and $g \in L^{p'}(\mathbb{R}^d), \quad \dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{1}{p'}=1$, the following Parseval identity holds
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)g(x)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathcal{F}f(\xi) \mathcal{F}g (\xi) d\xi \quad ? $$

Comment: $\left<f,g\right>:=\int_{\mathbb R^d}fg$.

Comment: And in that paragraph it is clearly stated that the formula holds for $f, g$ Schwartz functions (and hence by density for $L^2$). Also, the angled brackets are not the pairing between a vector space and its dual but the sesquilinear inner product on $L^2$.You can see the identity is meaningless for arbitrary $f, g$ in $L^1$ since products of $L^1$ functions need not be $L^1$.

Comment: But if I take, as I wrote, $f \in L^p$ and $g \in L^{p'}$ (so the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}fg$ is meaningful, is the identity still valid?